# Keep safari remote debugging open on navigation

Tags: safari, ios-simulator, remote-debugging

I'm using Safari's remote debugging to inspect a webview in an iPhone app in my simulator. The problem is that the remote debugging window closes as soon as the app does.

I have an action which switches to another app and back but I can't read console.log messages from immediately before the switch because I'm not quick enough and I can't read logs from immediately after coming back to my app because I have to re-open the console first.

Is there a way to keep it open so I can at least see the last logs from before switching apps?

Comment: This is a major annoyance, how hard would it be to leave the inspector open and keep a connection to the simulator alive?  Come on Apple!

Comment: For those that aren't dealing with switching apps, but have a similar problem, I get mileage out of issuing a `location.reload()` in the console

Answer (score 3):

Here is an AppleScript that launches Safari Inspector.  You can export it as an executable application and have it sitting in your dock to get into Inspector with a single click or launch it in a build phase in Xcode.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            set frontmost to true
            click menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu item "iPad Simulator" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Excellent! Today you need to use "iOS Simulator" instead of "iPad..".

Answer (score 1):

This is James' answer wrapped in an [Alfred Workflow](http://www.alfredapp.com/), -g- ... check it

ALSO WORKS FOR IPHONE BRAH

```
on alfred_script(q)
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            set frontmost to true
            try
                click menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu item "iPhone Simulator" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
            end try
            try
                click menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu item "iPad Simulator" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end alfred_script
```